# Array of Graphs in Spark Graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I've multiple graphs of same type. I want to store them in an array. But when I append a graph in array, I get the error that '++' operation is not suppotred in Graphs.

When I use this method:

```
var graphsArray = Array.empty[Graph[Object,Object]]
graphsArray :+ Graph(myVertices, myEdges)
```

I'm getting empty array, no values are being added.

Answer (score 0):

The default scala `Array` is **immutable**. This means the `:+` method is returning a new array with the new value, while `graphsArray` remains the same as when it was created (empty). As you're not assigning the result of `:+` to anything, you're losing the result.

If you want to use mutable array, you can use an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html). If you want to keep the default scala immutable behaviour, you can use `fold` to add all your graphs.

```
val emptyArray = Array.empty[Graph[Object, Object]]
val myGraphs = ...
val graphsArray = myGraphs.fold(emptyArray) { case (arr, elm) => arr :+ elm }
```